# Output statement proc glm

Tags: sas

SAS PROC GLM predicted output.

I am unable to generate a predicted output data from the GLM analysis:

```
* Proc glm output statement
proc glm data=sasuser.prova;
  class sesso age GIVLW;
  model SLA-HWLp_FS =sesso age GIVLW/SS3;
  output out=new predicted=SLA-HWLp_FS;
run;
```

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting. Can you expand your question to explain why you can't generate an output data set? What happens when you run the code shown above? If you get any errors in the log, please show them.

Comment: Note that `SLA-HWLp_FS` isn't a valid data set name - is that the error you're seeing?

Comment: yes please, that is the error I incur,

Comment: Please how do i generate the output file with the predicted values, since my output is always empty when i run the statement. (what is the right statement)

Comment: It's hard for anyone to help you unless you update your question to include some data and the log from your program. I'm not very familiar with PROC GLM but from the documentation (here: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect020.htm) your 'predicted = SLA-HWLp_FS' clause is invalid because it needs to specify a valid variable name; try it with 'predicted = sla' instead. It may also be that some other error is preventing the PROC from completing, so it's not even trying to write any output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first statement is a comment but the comment doesn't end with a `;` like it should.

   ```
   *Proc glm output statement;*<-missing the semicolon here;
   ```
2. SLA-HWLp_FS is not a valid SAS data set or variable name. I'll assume it's an underscore not a hyphen. You can check it by running a PROC CONTENTS on the data set and seeing the variable names.

   ```
   proc contents data=sasuser.prova;run;
   ```

If your variable does not have an underscore, you may need to refer to it using named literals notation, ie 'VARIABLE NAME'n which is the name in quotes and followed by an n immediately after the quotes.

This should work for you:

```
    proc glm data=sasuser.prova;
    class sesso age GIVLW;
    model SLA_HWLp_FS =sesso age GIVLW/SS3;
    output out=new predicted=SLA_HWLp_FS;
    run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and suggestions. I am using the statement proc glm;
   by group;
   class a;
   model y1-y5=a x(a);
   output out=pout predicted=py1-py5;
run;  (because i have more than one dependant variable) but  the code is not generating an output file with the predicted data.

Comment: ANS:  To generate the predicted values and residual a quit statement is required.   run; quit;